# Not able to pass value from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

**Code Updated with web.xml and Servlet configuration**

I am trying to forward some value from my servlet to JSP, but when I am trying to access that value into JSP, there is no output.

Here is my form:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="servlet/NewServlet">
Enter Name: <Input type="text" name="name"/><br>
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
</FORM>
```

Here is my Bean I am using for setter and getter methods:

```
package user;

    public class CompileClass {
    public String name;

    public void setName(String n){
            name=n;
        }

    public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Here is my servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import user.CompileClass;

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException{
String name1;

CompileClass c=new CompileClass();
name1=c.getName();
request.getSession().setAttribute("name1", name1);

request.getRequestDispatcher("../Result.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
    }
```

And finally here is my JSP page:

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="request" class="user.CompileClass" />
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="user"/>
<html>

  <body>

Name:
<br/>

<% request.getSession().getAttribute("name1");%>


  </body>
</html>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>NewServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/NewServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Everything seems fine to me. But still I am not getting any output on my JSP page. Help?

Answer (score 3):

How is the value from the form getting into your Bean?  You are doing:

```
CompileClass c=new CompileClass();      //creates a new, empty instance
name1=c.getName();                      //gets the name from the empty 
                                        //instance (will be null)
request.setAttribute("name1", name1);   //sets 'name1' to null in the request
```

You might have better luck if you do:

```
CompileClass c=new CompileClass();      //creates a new, empty instance
c.setName(request.getParameter("name"));//get the param and set it in the bean
name1=c.getName();                      //gets the name from the bean
request.setAttribute("name1", name1);   //sets 'name1' in the request
```

Although from the structure of your code, it seems like you are probably using some web framework that you expect to populate the Bean automatically for you with data from the request.  If so, then you may want to consult the configuration and usage docs for your framework to make sure that you have it set up correctly and that you are using it correctly.

Edit:

Also, please do not do things like:

`<% request.getSession().getAttribute("name1");%>`

Use this instead:

`${name1}`

Edit 2:

You aren't deploying your servlet in `web.xml`.  You need to configure it by adding something like:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>newServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>user.NewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>newServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/name/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then you need to update your form HTML so that the form posts to the servlet instead of directly to the JSP.  So something like:

`<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="name/submit">`

Comment: I tried your modified code didn't worked. Also I removed the constructor and then tried, but that too didn't worked.

This is no web framework. Just that the general outline of our web app that we have designed and trying to stick to this structure.

Comment: @Anurag - Then can you also post your `web.xml` file?  Assuming that everything is hooked up correctly, the above code should work.

Comment: @Anurag - That explains it then, you haven't deployed your servlet.  You need to add a configuration section for your servlet, like:  `<servlet>
      <servlet-name>nameServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>user.NewServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>nameServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/name/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>`, and then set the `action` on your to something like `ACTION="name/submit"`, and then you should be good to go.

Comment: @aroth I updated the web.xml and added appropriate configuration. I have also updated web.xml here. Also in the index.jsp I have modified: `<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="servlet/NewServlet">`

But still on the Result.jsp page there is no output :| 

 Where am I wrong now?

Comment: @Anurag - Hard to say.  Have you tried adding some `System.out.println()` calls in your servlet to verify that it is being called?  If it is, then maybe try using `request.getRequestDispatcher("../Result.jsp").include(request, response);` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @aroth I removed the bean and the result.jsp page and directly taking the params from index.php and processing and printing from servlet. Now it is working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, like trouble with scopes.  The easiest way to fix it is replace

```
request.setAttribute("name1", name1);
```

to

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("name1", name1);
```

Comment: I tried changing the request call with session but didn't worked.

Comment: I tried all that is being pointed here. But again no output. Also I have updated the code here.

Comment: @Anurag - try include instead of forward.

Comment: @stas I removed the bean and the result.jsp page and directly taking the params from index.php and processing and printing from servlet. Now it is working. Thanks for the help anyhow.

Comment: @Stas `index.jsp` my bad :| I meant the initial JSP form

Answer (score -2):

use RequestDispatcher class...

Comment: Read the question, that's what he did: `request.getRequestDispatcher("../Result.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: along with request dispatcher we can pass values to just next page. that what he want ..

Comment: If you believed that to be the case, then why didn't you explain that in your answer?